# Change list image item on click

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a list with a defined *list-style-image* and *hover* so as every time the user goes through the list, the image changes.

That's ok. What i would like to do is that when the user clicks on the item, the clicked item changes to another image accordingly either selected or not.

So far this is my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lonz0w/)

CSS

```
#FavListApp {
    list-style-image: url('../images/FavStarUnSel.png');
    list-style-position: inside;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover { list-style-image: url('../images/FavStarSel.png'); }
```

HTML

```
<ul id="FavListApp">

    <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Dragon App</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Calculator</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Brain Academy</a></li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="#">Root Words</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#FavListApp li > a').click(function(){

                $(this).parent().find('#FavListApp').css('listStyleImage','url(../images/FavStarUnSel.png)')
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's not working ? And why not put the "margin-bottom: 20px;" in your CSS ?

Comment: I did that to try to arrange the image to be centered to the text

Comment: Would be great to have a JSFiddle or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m81bb0q7/)

```
$('#FavListApp li > a').on("click",function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $link = $(this);
  $link.toggleClass("selected");
  $link.parent().css('listStyleImage', $link.hasClass("selected")?sel:unsel);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` in this context

```
$('#FavListApp li > a').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').css('listStyleImage','url(../images/FavStarUnSel.png)')
});
```

Comment: That changes all of my list images... I want to change one only. What I want is to change that specific item if clicked

Comment: you apply changes for li or ul?

Comment: Yes I applied changes for ul

Comment: You cannot change the listStyleImage for a UL and expect it to only affect one LI

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

(EDIT : Added toggle)

```
var selectedImage = 'url(../images/FavStarSel.png)'
var unselectedImage = 'url(../images/FavStarUnSel.png)'

$('#FavListApp li > a').click(function(){
  //Remember current state
  var li = $(this).parent()
  var currentImage = li.css('listStyleImage')    

  //Revert all items to default image
  $("#FavListApp li").css("list-style-image", unselectedImage);

  //Toggle current selected li image
  if (currentImage === selectedImage){
      li.css('listStyleImage', unselectedImage)
  }
  else{
      li.css('listStyleImage', selectedImage)
  }
});
```

Comment: ok that worked... the next bit is to un-select the item if it is selected

Comment: Un-select doesn't work ? The second line `revert all items to default` should do it though...

Comment: Aaaah sorry, you mean by clicking on it again :D, just wait a sec

Comment: Aaaah sorry still not working, I have to remember the current list item state, just a moment.

Comment: Thanks for your help but now, if I click another li the previous li becomes unselected and if I click on the selected li it does not change :(

Comment: Yes it's because of the hover that changes the CSS to the same image as when you click it. But nvm mplungjan's solution is excellent, so go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh just thought of a CSS trick.

Basically, you have a links that have just a "#" href, why not make point them to an ID (even if it doesn't exist ?)

Dragon App
    Calculator
    Brain Academy
    Root Words

Then make ue of the CSS `:active` property

```
#FavListApp {
    list-style-image: url('../images/FavStarUnSel.png');
    list-style-position: inside;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover, ul li:active { list-style-image: url('../images/FavStarSel.png'); }
```

Comment: Oh well sorry this won't handle the "toggle"